# Hamiltonian Cycle with fork

Tags: c, fork, cycle

hellow friends 
i want to write Hamiltonian Cycle for 5 vertexes with fork. and i want to create a process for each vertex to check is it true vertex in (hamCycleUtil function )or no. so i write this code but it has false output.i cant solve the problem .pleas help.how can i write this code true ?i just want create 5 process to check the vertexes.

```
 /*
     * C Program to Find Hamiltonian Cycle
     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #define V 5

    void printSolution(int path[]);

    /* 
     * check if the vertex v can be added at index 'pos' in the Hamiltonian Cycle 
     */
    bool isSafe(int v, bool graph[V][V], int path[], int pos)
    {




        if (graph [path[pos-1]][v] == 0)
            return false;

       for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            if (path[i] == v)
           return false;

        return true;
    }

    /* solve hamiltonian cycle problem */
    bool hamCycleUtil(bool graph[V][V], int path[], int pos)
    {
      int pid;
        int s=-1;//counter
        if (pos == V)
        {
            if (graph[ path[pos-1] ][ path[0] ] == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        for (int v = 1; v < V; v++)
        {
             pid=fork();
            s++;
            if(s<V)// to control the number of fork
            {
            if(v==1)
            {
                pid=1;}
            pid=fork();
            s++;
            if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error");
               }
            else if (pid == 0){
           if (isSafe(v, graph, path, pos))
            {
                path[pos] = v;
                if (hamCycleUtil (graph, path, pos+1) == true)
                    return true;
                path[pos] = -1;
            } 
            }
         else  {
            if (isSafe(v, graph, path, pos))
            {
                path[pos] = v;
                if (hamCycleUtil (graph, path, pos+1) == true)
                    return true;
                path[pos] = -1;
            } 
         }
        }   
        }

            return false;
    }

    /* solves the Hamiltonian Cycle problem using Backtracking.*/
    bool hamCycle(bool graph[V][V])
    {
        int *path = malloc(V*sizeof(int));


        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            path[i] = -1;
        path[0] = 0;
        if (hamCycleUtil(graph, path, 1) == false)
        {
          printf("\nSolution does not exist");
            return false;
        }
        printSolution(path);
        return true;
    }

    /* Main */
    void printSolution(int path[])
    {
        printf("Solution Exists:");
        printf(" Following is one Hamiltonian Cycle \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            printf(" %d",path[i]);
        printf(" %d",path[0]);
    }

    int main()
    {



       /* Let us create the following graph
          (0)--(1)--(2)
           |   / \   |
           |  /   \  |
           | /     \ |
          (3)-------(4)    */


       bool graph1[V][V] = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                          {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                          {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                          {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                          {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                         };

        { hamCycle(graph1);

       /* Let us create the following graph
          (0)--(1)--(2)
           |   / \   |
           |  /   \  |
           | /     \ |
          (3)       (4)    */
        bool graph2[V][V] = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                          {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                          {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                          {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                         };

            hamCycle(graph2);
        return 0;
        }}
```

Comment: I haven't tried to understand the program, but in the first `pid = fork();`, you never look at the value of `pid`. That can't be right.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.